# Add code to a method without edit Magento core file

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch, extend, magento-core

I'm in this condition:

[image]

Magento 2.3.4 with Elasticsuite installed and I want to customize the search box so when `#search` get focus the page get darker adding a `<div class"blury"></div>`. I already make it work doing like this:

I added `require-config.js` on my theme:

```
var config = {
    deps: [
    'js/custom'
    ]
};
```

I added `web/js/custom.js`:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia'
], function($, mediaCheck){
    "use strict";

    mediaCheck({
        media: '(min-width: 768px)',
        // Switch to Desktop Version
        entry: function () {

            $('#search').focus(function() {
                $('body').append('<div class="blury"></div>');
                $('.blury').css({
                    "background-color": "black",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "height": "100%",
                    "width": "100%",
                    "top": "0",
                    "left": "0",
                    "opacity": "0.7",
                    "z-index": "900",
                })
            })

            $('#search').focusout(function() {
                $('.blury').remove();
            })

        },
        // Switch to Mobile Version
        exit: function () {
            $('.blury').remove();
        }
    });
})
```

### The problem

As you can see from the video, every time I click or press ESC key to remove the focus from the searchbox the first time the focus come back to the searchbox so I need to click outside a second time to remove the focus.

To solve this I added to `vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/web/js/form-mini.js` on the `_create` method `$('#search').blur()` at 97 line:

```
...
        _create: function () {
            this.responseList = {
                indexList: null,
                selected: null
            };
            this.autoComplete = $(this.options.destinationSelector);
            this.searchForm = $(this.options.formSelector);
            this.submitBtn = this.searchForm.find(this.options.submitBtn)[0];
            this.searchLabel = this.searchForm.find(this.options.searchLabel);
            this.isExpandable = this.options.isExpandable;

            _.bindAll(this, '_onKeyDown', '_onPropertyChange', '_onSubmit');

            this.submitBtn.disabled = true;

            this.element.attr('autocomplete', this.options.autocomplete);

            mediaCheck({
                media: '(max-width: 768px)',
                entry: function () {
                    this.isExpandable = true;
                }.bind(this),
                exit: function () {
                    this.isExpandable = true;
                }.bind(this)
            });

            this.searchLabel.on('click', function (e) {
                // allow input to lose its' focus when clicking on label
                if (this.isExpandable && this.isActive()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }.bind(this));

            this.element.on('blur', $.proxy(function () {
                if (!this.searchLabel.hasClass('active')) {
                    return;
                }

                setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                    if (this.autoComplete.is(':hidden')) {
                        this.setActiveState(false);
                    } else {
                        this.element.trigger('focus');
                    }
                    this.autoComplete.hide();
                    $('#search').blur()
                    this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                }, this), 250);
            }, this));

            if (this.element.get(0) === document.activeElement) {
                this.setActiveState(true);
            }

            this.element.on('focus', this.setActiveState.bind(this, true));
            this.element.on('keydown', this._onKeyDown);
            // Prevent spamming the server with requests by waiting till the user has stopped typing for period of time
            this.element.on('input propertychange', _.debounce(this._onPropertyChange, this.options.suggestionDelay));

            this.searchForm.on('submit', $.proxy(function (e) {
                this._onSubmit(e);
                this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
            }, this));
        },
...
```

**but this, as you know, is not ideal since I edited a Magento core file.**

This method is also then extended by ElasticSuite with `vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/view/frontend/web/js/form-mini.js`.

### My question

How can I add `$('#search').blur()` there without edit the Magento core file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mixin to override core js file

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Search/form-mini': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/mixins/form-mini': true
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Create file at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/mixins/form-mini.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'matchMedia',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, mediaCheck) {

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('custom.quickSearch', widget, {
            _init: function () {
                alert("I'm here");
            }
        });
        return $.custom.quickSearch;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I got no error message in console but Elasticsuite search popup isn't shown anymore. What should the _init method supposed to do? And how can I "inject" my jQuery function inside Grandparent _create method?